# Init array in a function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am absolutely new to C and I tried to initialize a array in a function.

But it doesn't work, because if I want to print the values in the main method I always get a Segmentation fault.

```
 static void array(int *i)
{
    int j = 0;
    i = (int *) malloc(5 * sizeof (int));
    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        i[j] = j;
    }

    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        printf("Hello: %d\n", i[j]);
    }
}

/* Main entry point */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int j;
    int *i = NULL;

    array(i);
    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        printf("Hello: %d\n", i[j]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Would be nice if someone could fix the code and could explain how it works.

Comment: `i = (int *) malloc(5 * sizeof (int));` only affects the copy of the pointer the function got, not the pointer in the caller. Let me find a duplicate.

Comment: In other words: the pointer is passed as value, not as reference, and thus doesn't get updated. The value for i got its original value when you exit array() function.

Comment: Don't cast the result of `malloc`.

Comment: But I think we have to cast the result of malloc the be compatible with c++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
static void array(int **i)
{
    int j = 0;
    *i = malloc(5 * sizeof (int));
    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        (*i)[j] = j;
    }

    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        printf("Hello: %d\n", (*i)[j]);
    }
}

/* Main entry point */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int j;
    int *i = NULL;

    array(&i);
    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        printf("Hello: %d\n", i[j]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You are passing a pointer by value into array, so what you need to do is pass a pointer to your pointer instead, then set/use that.

---

As for why you shouldn't cast the result of a malloc, see: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) and 
[Specifically, what's dangerous about casting the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565496/specifically-whats-dangerous-about-casting-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: Lets say that we want to copy a other array int this one: how would i work: memcpy(*i, j, 5* sizeof (int)); 

Why do I have to use *i and not &i in this function?

Comment: in `array` `i` is a pointer to your `i` in main, so to refer to that `i` in main, you have to use `*i`.

Comment: As for your `memcpy` question, lookup `memcpy`, it expects two pointers and a size to copy, just make sure you pass it the `i` in your main (either by dereferencing `i` in `array` or doing the `memcpy` in `main`.). You also need your second argument to be a pointer as well, so using `j` doesn't make sense since `j` is an integer.

Comment: Remove the superfluous, dangerous cast of malloc's return value and I'll upvote this. I know it is there in the OP's code, but we shouldn't teach anyone to do that.

Comment: Done, with a note about why casting malloc is bad

Answer (score 1):

In order to allocate memory to a variable from within a function, you must pass a pointer to a pointer as the function argument, dereference the pointer and then allocate the memory.

or in pseudo-code

```
function(int **i)
{
    *i = malloc...
}
int *i = NULL;
function(&i);
```

This is one of the ways to do it. You could also return the pointer which malloc returns.
And, from the material I've read, it's a good practice to NOT cast the return type of malloc.